# Replace messages array from the validation MessageBag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a class that extends FormRequest class in which I want to replace the entire message array with a new message array

This is my method in which successfully fetch old messages but now want to replace the existing MessageBag array with `$uniqueMessages`  array

```
/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $validationMessages = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
        $uniqueMessages = array_unique($validationMessages, SORT_REGULAR);
        //Require Stuff that set  $uniqueMessages array to the MessageBag
    });
}
```

I know we can add extra messages using  this `$validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');`

But I want to replace the existing messages with a new one

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: @V-K I don't want to customize, but I want to remove the duplicate message for the array field that's why I want to replace existing message with unique message array